# Start Jenkins job within a parent job without wait for child to finish

Tags: jenkins

Im using Multijob plugin to run child jobs from parent job.

When a child job called, the main job waits for it to finish before continue execution.

I would like the parent to call a child and continue execution immediately. it should also finish with SUCCESS without rely on the child (the child is cleaning environments, this job is very long and should not FAIL the parent job if it fails)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to do it with triggering the job by HTTP POST:

```
curl -s -X POST "http://user:pass@jenkins-ip:8080/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?token=mytoken&K1=${K1}&K2=${K2}"
```

This sends a trigger to start a job, and continue without waits.

NOTES: child job needs to be configured to 'triggered remotely' with a token for http call.

Answer (score 0):

from Jenkins documentation: [Pipeline: Build Step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/)

> propagate (optional)
> If enabled (default state), then the result of this step is that of the downstream build (e.g., success, unstable, failure, not built, or aborted). If disabled, then this step succeeds even if the downstream build is unstable, failed, etc.; use the result property of the return value as needed.
> Type: boolean

> wait (optional)
> If true, the pipeline will wait for the result of the build step before jumping to the next step. Defaults to true.
> Type: boolean

so all what you need is to set wait to false and propagate to false
Example:

```
build job: "child-job", wait: false, propagate: false
```